# Passing parameters to class constructor from a wrapper function

Tags: php, oop

Here is the deal.
I'm trying to make a function which returns an object. Something like this:

```
function getObject( $objectName ) {
    return new $objectName() ;
}
```

But i still need to pass params to the class constructor, easiest solution would be passing to the function an array, like this:

```
function getObject( $objectName, $arr = array() ) {
    return new $objectName( $arr ) ;
}
```

But then i need the class constructor had only 1 argument and exactly array, which is undesired, cause i want to be able to use this function for any class.
Here is the solution i came to:

```
/**
 * Test class
 */
class Class1 {
    /**
     * Class constructor just to check if the function below works
     */
    public function __construct( $foo, $bar ) {
        echo $foo . ' _ ' . $bar ;
    }
}

/**
 * This function retrns a class $className object, all that goes after first argument passes to the object class constructor as params
 * @param String $className - class name
 * @return Object - desired object
 */
function loadClass( $className ) {
    $vars = func_get_args() ; // get arguments
    unset( $vars[ 0 ] ) ; // unset first arg, which is $className
    // << Anonymous function code start >>
    $code = 'return new ' . $className . '(' ;
    $auxCode = array() ;
    foreach( $vars as $val )
        $auxCode[] =    'unserialize( stripslashes(\''
        .               addslashes( ( serialize( $val ) ) ) . '\' ) )' ;
    $code .= implode( ',', $auxCode ) . ');' ;
    // << Anonymous function code end >>
    $returnClass = create_function( '', $code ) ; // create the anonymous func
    return $returnClass( $vars ) ; // return object
}

$obj = loadClass( 'Class1', 'l\'ol', 'fun' ) ; // test
```

Well, it works just as i want, but looks a bit clumsy to me. Maybe i'm reinventing the wheel and there is another standard solution or something for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ReflectionClass` to achieve this easily:

```
function getObject($objectName, $arr = array()) {
    if (empty($arr)) {
        // Assumes you correctly pass nothing or array() in the second argument
        // and that the constructor does accept no arguments
        return new $objectName();
    } else {
        // Similar to call_user_func_array() but on an object's constructor
        // May throw an exception if you don't pass the correct argument set
        // or there's no known constructor other than the default (arg-less)
        $rc = new ReflectionClass($objectName);
        return $rc->newInstanceArgs($arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Reflection... is there anything it CANNOT do?! :)

Comment: Thanx a lot! I was quite sure there is the way to use ReflectionClass, but didn't dig deep enough. Damned docs is a mess.

Comment: @k0stix: Yeah, sadly :( Remember to click the check mark to accept an answer (this is just your second question so I'm letting you know).

Comment: Right. Thanks again. Would be glad to raise you reputation, but it seems like one have to deserve this honor here =)

Comment: @k0stix: You can always ask another question, accept another answer, then come back and vote. But the +15 I get from accepting my answer is more than enough, really :)